# How to build docbook 4.2 docs on Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, postgresql, arch-linux

I'm trying to build documentation for PostgreSQL HEAD. It requires docbook 4.2, which I installed, but still the problem exist.

I described it in detail - including error messages, lists of packages, and configure options in [mail](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-general/2009-11/msg00325.php) to postgresql general mailing list.

Do you have any idea what to do to be able to build those docs?

Comment: An Arch Linux Bounty Question?! OMG.

Comment: @Joseph: I need those docs.

Comment: Have you tried the #archlinux irc channel? Do you have to use 4.2? I noticed there's a 4.5 in AUR ...

Comment: @Joseph - yes I tried. Yes, I have to - these are PostgreSQL docs, and I have no influence over source format.

Answer (score 1):

These 'no' strings in `./configure` output are okay: the script just tests the system capabilities.

As far as I understand, there's an error in `/etc/xml/catalog`. It also depends on some files in /etc/xml, which in turn uses definitions from `/usr/share/xml`, you may be missing something. Try [the archive I've prepared for you](http://www.sendspace.com/file/446kw3) and overwrite your `/etc/xml` & `/usr/share/xml` with its contents (backup first!). I believe it should really help.

Comment: I know system checks capabilities, but it doesn't let me (later on) build docs. Which is not ok, as I need those docs.

Comment: Ehm, have you tried my suggestion?